# Unable to use the variable for comparison in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I'm not able to use the variable var2. What is wrong in this script?

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$(---some shell cmd---)
echo $var1

read USER_ID

ssh $USER_ID@xx.xx.xx.xx '

var2=$(---some shell cmd---)
echo $var2
'

if [ "$var1" -eq "$var2" ]; then    
    echo "success\n"
fi
```

Comment: why did you used single quotes after ssh which ending after `echo $var2` ?

Comment: I want to access the server remotely. var1 will store the result from local machine and var2 stores from remote machine. I want to compare the results and act upon it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `var2` only lives on the remote computer. You need to capture the value on your own box.

```
var2=$(ssh $USER_ID@xx.xx.xx.xx 'some shell command')
```

EDIT: just to make myself more clear:

The synopsis of the SSH command is:

```
ssh user@host [command]
```

The `command` runs entirely on the remote machine, it takes its standard input from the local terminal via SSH and prints both its stdout and stderr to the local terminal via SSH.

In case of

```
ssh user@host 'var2=$(command)'
```

a `var2` variable is created on the remote machine and it captures the stdout of `command` also on the remote machine. No `var2` is created on the local box.

But if you run the command substitution on the local box, by including the entire SSH command in `$()` it does work, the output of the remote command is captured in the local variable:

```
var2=$(ssh user@host 'command')
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error::: E000002: Can't open file '/svn/repos/format': No such file or directory
test.sh: 33: [: Illegal number:

Comment: Do you receive it when assigning to var2?

Comment: Yes, reason being the scope of variables are changing.

Comment: I assume test.sh is the mysterious `some shell command`. Did you test it on the remote machine in an interactive ssh session? BTW there is a hint in the error message: there is no `/svn/repos/format` file on the remote machine.

Comment: Better post the script as part of the question, it's unreadable this way. But I already see it's interactive, as it reads 3 input lines from the user (DUMP_REPOS, REMOTE_USER_ID, SVN_REPOS). Did you enter the appropriate data? The read of SVN_REPOS is done on a 3rd host, as test.sh opens another ssh session for that command. When you read something from the user, you never prompt him for it, so how does he know what to enter? But if you do, be careful to print the prompts to stderr, otherwise the prompts go into the variables captured by $().

Comment: Indeed it's interactive which is required. echo is happening properly. Let's say SVN_CLIENT_YOUNGEST = 100 and if I'm comparing this var with 100, it's prompting the correct last message. But if SVN_CLIENT_YOUNGEST is compared with $SVN_SERVER_YOUNGEST, then I'm receiving this error----- test.sh: 34: [: Illegal number:

Comment: The `illegal number` (I speculate) refers to the fact that `var2` is the empty string and you are trying `[ "$var1" -eq "$var2" ]`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes you are correct. Since ssh is creating another sub-process (may be it's wrong terminology), hence the scope of variable has changed. So how to export var2 to parent process.

Comment: "how to export var2 to parent process"  - you can't.  Environment variables are *copied* from parent to child when the new process is created.

Comment: @cdarke Could you please tell me how to proceed with the comparison of those two variables ?

Comment: You need to pass the values in some way, either by printing to stdout, or using some form of inter process communication.